# Как вывести переменную k?

Tags: c++

Есть два кода в одном эта переменная выводится нормально в другом нет(почему?) алгоритм вроде один и тот же.

```
int* masa, * masb = NULL;
int cc , rr, k;

cout << "enter size of array" << endl << "rr: ";
cin >> rr;
cout << endl << "cc: ";
cin >> cc;
masa = (int*)malloc(rr * cc * sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < rr; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cc; j++)
    {
        *(masa + i * rr + j) = rand() % 20;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < rr; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cc; j++)
    {
        cout << *(masa+ i * rr + j) << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
//утворення масива що більший за 2 
cout << endl;
for (int i = 0,k = 0; i < rr; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < cc; j++)
    {
        
        if (*(masa + i * rr + j) > 2)
        {
            masb = (int*)realloc(masb, (k + 1) * sizeof(int));


            masb[k] = *(masa + i * rr + j);


            k++;
        }
        
    }

    
cout << k;
```

Вот другой код в котором все работет

```
int* a; // Вказівник на масив, початкова адреса для зберігання елементів масиву
int* b = NULL; // Вказівник на масив, розмір якого не відомо завчасно
int i, j, rr, cc, k;
printf("Введіть кількість рядків масиву n \n"); scanf(" %d", &rr);
printf("Введіть кількість стовпчиків масиву m \n"); scanf(" %d", &cc);
a = (int*)malloc(rr * cc * sizeof(int)); // Виділення пам'яті під масив
printf("Введня елементів масиву \n");
for (i = 0; i < rr; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < cc; j++)
        *(a + i * cc + j) = rand() % 10; //або з клавіатури scanf("%d", a+i*cc+j);

printf("Друк елементів масиву \n");
for (i = 0; i < rr; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < cc; j++)
        printf("%6d", *(a + i * cc + j));
    printf("\n");
}
for (i = 0, k = 0; i < rr; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < cc; j++)
    {
        if (*(a + i * cc + j) > 2)
        {
            b = (int*)realloc(b, (k + 1) * sizeof(int)); // Вказівник на новий

            

                b[k] = *(a + i * cc + j);
            k++;
        }
    }
cout << k;
```

Comment: У вас неинициализированная переменная `k`. Мне кажется, что в этом коде ошибка, на первый взгляд. Возможна так же проблема с перераспределением памяти.

Comment: @Miracle- переменная инициализируется в цикле `for (i = 0, k = 0; i < rr; i++)`

Comment: @DmitryK Так ведь она локальной считается. Разве нет?(говорю про первый код).

Comment: @Miracle- Нет. Если бы было вот так `for (int k = 0;  ;  )` - то это была бы новая локальная переменная с таким же именем.

Comment: @DmitryK Мне кажется вы ошибаетесь. Пока проверить не могу, так что промолчу.

Comment: Больше смущает перевыделение памяти под новый массив на каждом шаге. Проще выделить памяти столько же, сколько в первом массиве, записать туда нужные данные, и перевыделить в сторону уменьшения. Или при вводе/генерации посчитать количество элементов больше 2 и сразу выделить массив нужного размера.

Comment: @Miracle- Да, вы правы. Я посмотрел во второй код. В первом коде k - новая локальная переменная, во втором коде - переменная объявленная в начале программы. Я сначала не заметил разницы между вариантами.

Comment: @Miracle- оформите как ответ - это действительно найденная ошибка.

Comment: @DmitryK - Да нет,переменная и там и там объявленная в начале программы. 
Вот первый код "int cc , rr, k;" 2 строка,
вот второй "int i, j, rr, cc, k;" 3 строка

Comment: Нет. Как написал @Miracle- в первом варианте вы в теле цикла `for (int i = 0,k = 0; i < rr; i++)` объявляете ещё одну локальную переменную `k` , которая не имеет отношения к переменной, объявленной в начале программы. И переменная `i` - тоже. Просто они имеют разные области видимости. И эта переменная уничтожится сразу после выхода из цикла.

Comment: @DmitryK Но ведь во втором варианте она тоже там есть но оно как то работает О_о.
И не выдает ошибку про то что переменная К не инициализирована.

Comment: В первом варианте у вас есть объявление новых переменных `for( int `, а во втором такого объявления нет - `for( `, поэтому используются ранее объявленные (в начале программы) переменные. А работает оно правильно. Просто переменная к внутри цикла считает количество, всё правильно записывается, а потом она умирает. А на печать вы выводите переменную, объявленную в начале программы. Но в ней нет никакой полезной информации. И да - она не инициализировалась никаким значением.

Comment: @DmitryK Cпасибо!Это действительно так как вы сказали.

Comment: @DmitryK Сам на всякий случай проверил. Все верно. Да мне кажется вы сами прекрасно объяснили)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот этот код

```
for (int i = 0,k = 0; i < rr; i++)
```

объявляет переменные `i` и `k` как локальные для тела цикла. Чем, собственно, все и поясняется. `k` в цикле и `k` после цикла — две разные переменные...